# Python .join[] multiplys total string characters across multiple lines

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, random, concatenation

I am working on a personal project to help my understanding of python 3.4.2 looping and concatenating strings from multiple sources.

My goal with this is to take 'string' use join and call `__len__()` inside to build a string it is multiplying my results. I would like the lengths to be 5 then 10 then 15. Right now it is coming out 5 then 25 then 105. If I keep going I get 425,1705,6825,etc...

I hope I'm missing something simple, but any help would be amazing. I'm also trying to do my joins efficiently (I know the prints aren't, those are for debugging purposes.)

I used a visualized python tool online to step through it and see if I could figure it out. I just am missing something. 
http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Thank you in advance!

```
import random

def main():
    #String values will be pulled from
    string = 'valuehereisheldbythebeholderwhomrolledadtwentyandcriticalmissed'

    #Initial string creation
    strTest = ''
    print('strTest Blank: ' + strTest)

    #first round string generation
    strTest = strTest.join([string[randomIndex(string.__len__())] for i in range(randomLength())])
    print('strTest 1: ' + strTest)
    print('strTest 1 length: ' + str(strTest.__len__()))

    #second round string generation
    strTest = strTest.join([string[randomIndex(string.__len__())] for i in range(randomLength())])
    print('strTest 2: ' + strTest)
    print('strTest 2 length: ' + str(strTest.__len__()))

    #final round string generation
    strTest = strTest.join([string[randomIndex(string.__len__())] for i in range(randomLength())])
    print('strTest 3: ' + strTest)
    print('strTest 3 length: ' + str(strTest.__len__()))

def randomIndex(index):
    #create random value between position 0 and total string length to generate string
    return random.randint(0,index)

def randomLength():
    #return random length for string creation, static for testing
    return 5
    #return random.randint(10,100)

main()
# output desired is 
# strTest 1 length: 5
# strTest 2 length: 10
# strTest 3 length: 15
```

Comment: What do you think `join` does? Because `s.join(strings)` doesn't just stick the `strings` on the end of `s`.

Comment: Ah, you are right. I tested

string = 'abcd'
test = ''.join(string)
test = test.join(string)
test = test.join(string)

and got 4,16,52. I see what you mean, it is not just placing them on the end of the string. I will need to look at join more and see if I can figure out how to maintain the index and grow the string. May be easier to put this all in an array then pull it out when I need to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code runs without any issue, what's happening actually is, each time you call `strTest.join(...)`, you are actually joining each random character and the next you get from `string` with the previous value of `strTest`.

Quoting from Python Doc:

> `str.join(iterable)` Return a string which is the concatenation of the
>   strings in the iterable iterable. A TypeError will be raised if there
>   are any non-string values in iterable, including bytes objects. **The
>   separator between elements is the string providing this method.**

**Example:**

```
>>> s = 'ALPHA'
>>> '*'.join(s)
'A*L*P*H*A'
>>> s = 'TEST'
>>> ss = '-long-string-'
>>> ss.join(s)
'T-long-string-E-long-string-S-long-string-T'
```

So probably you want something like:

```
strTest = strTest + ''.join([string[randomIndex(string.__len__())] for i in range(randomLength())])
```

Comment: Thank you, it was exactly that. I have changed to add the + ''.join and it is now performing how I was wanting. Thank you again!

Comment: @toredOut ..no pblm..Just keep reading documentation to grasp correct functioning of the methods